# ¿Cómo saber el nombre del micrófono que se está usando?

Tags: java, android

Mi problema es que no encuentro la forma de saber el nombre o tecnología del micrófono desde el código. ¿Cómo saber el nombre o tecnología del micrófono que se está usando en un dispositivo con Android desde código?

Comment: ¿Tienes ya el código para controlar/leer el micrófono? Deberías compartirlo

Comment: podrias agregar tu codigo porfavor para ayudarte mejor.

Comment: En el momento no lo tengo, pero si lo he hecho en varias ocasiones. lo que no he podido es encontrar la forma de ver la tecnología o el modelo del micrófono que se esta usando.